# How to avoid Cuda race condition, for parallel comparison of values in a hash map

Tags: parallel-processing, hashmap, cuda, race-condition

I have a problem where in a 2D space (x,y) I have a lot of points with different sizes. An array with the struct (x,y, size) represents this space. I want to downsample this space to some specific grid where x, and y are rounded to the closest cell of the grid and then I keep the biggest size in a cell. My idea is to use a hash map where I keep 1D indices mapped from 2D indices, keep the biggest size in a hash map of (key: 1d index, value: biggest size) and then create the output based on this hash map. Here is the code inside my kernel where I find the biggest size:

```
  //nx: is the grid size in x
  //dx/dy: is the cell size in x/y
  //points: is the structure keeping the 2d points with the size as (x,y,size)
  //minBounds: has the minimum values of x and y

  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x
  std::unordered_map<uint64_t, float> indexSizeMap;

  // Find point index in the grid and flatten it to 1d index
  auto xi = static_cast<uint64_t>(round((points[i].x - minBounds.x) / dx));
  auto yi = static_cast<uint64_t>(round((points[i].y - minBounds.y) / dy));
  uint64_t index1d = to1dIndex(xi, yi, nx + 1); //mapping 2d index to 1d index

  // If the index in the voxel grid is vacant, fill it. Otherwise keep the larger size
  if (indexSizeMap.count(index1d))
  {
     if (indexSizeMap[index1d] < points[i].size)
     {
        indexSizeMap[index1d] = points[i].size;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     indexSizeMap[index1d] = points[i].size;
  }
```

Now I figured out that this part of the code might have a race condition, making it non-deterministic since there might be two threads filling the same index at the same time:

```
  if (indexSizeMap.count(index1d))
  {
     if (indexSizeMap[index1d] < points[i].size)
     {
        indexSizeMap[index1d] = points[i].size;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     indexSizeMap[index1d] = points[i].size;
  }
```

Looking into documents about race conditions I saw a lot of ways to handle +/- operations but I didn't find how to handle this case. Do you know a way to avoid race conditions in this case or do you suggest another implementation?

Comment: atomic operations can be used to implement mutual exclusion.

Comment: I would simply sort the points by `index1d`, then perform max reduce by key where key is `index1d` and value is `size`

Comment: I'm not sure if it really fits this use case, but [NVIDIA/cuCollections](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuCollections) tries to implement performant GPU hash tables.

Comment: See [`cuda::atomic_ref::fetch_max`](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/extended_api/synchronization_primitives/atomic_ref.html#atomic-extrema-operations).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was another implementation:
Since using the hash maps in a Cuda kernel wasn't working great for me, I ended up replacing the hashmap with an array of the same size as my points.
I keep the indices there. A second CUDA kernel (which is 2d) was used to remove the points that have another point with a bigger size. So I'll end up with the points I need.